# Testing express.js app in own environment with dummy db

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js

I've got the following structure for my web app

db.js:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
db = mongoose.createConnection("...");
playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // my schema stuff
});
exports.Player = db.model("player", playerSchema);
```

I have all my routes in an own file (route/index.js):

```
db = require('../db');

exports.createPlayer = function(req, res) {
  player = new db.Player();
  player.name = req.body.player_name;
  player.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      log(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
};
```

app.js

```
routes = require('./routes');
app.post("/start", routes.createPlayer);
```

I test the app using mocha, should and supertest like the following example

```
should = require('should');
supertest = require('supertest');
app = require('../app');

describe("POST /start", function() {
  it("should redirect", function(done) {
    supertest(app)
    .post("/start")
    .send({
      player_name: "John Wayne"
    }).end(function(err, res) {
      should.not.exist(err);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

It all works fine but I don't want to test against my production database. Does anyone know a smart way to use a dummy/different db just for testing? Maybe using a different environment? I'm kind of stuck!

Comment: When you connecting to MondoDB you can specify host, port and db name. You may store this options in some config file. You may even divide your production, development and testing configs, loading one of them depending on current `NODE_ENV` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a common.js file that is the first file that I include in my test files. At the top is this:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV    = 'test'
process.env.MONGOHQ_URL = 'mongodb://localhost/project-testing'
```

And when I do my database connection I have it like this:

```
var dbUri = process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/project'
var db    = mongoose.connect(dbUri)
```

Comment: this is the best, setup a config.development.js and a config.production.js

Comment: I prefer to have a config/environment.js that will make use of NODE_ENV to set different properties. Passwords that shouldn't be checked into version control are expected to be environment vars (like MONGOHQ_URL)